# Rails CMS: static files or database records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, dita

I'm trying to figure out the cut-off with respect to when a "text entry" should be stored in the database vs. as a static file.  Are there any rules of thumb here?  The text entries will be at the most several paragraphs and have links to images and tables (and hyperlinks to other text entries).  Some criteria for the text entry:

1. I'm thinking of using DITA as the content format
2. The text should be searchable
3. If the text is revised, a new version will be created

thanks in advance, Chuck

Answer (score 0):

The "rails way" would be using a database.

The solution will be more scalable, therefore faster and probably easier to develop with (using migration and so on). Using the file system, you will have to build lots of functions on your own, that are already implemented for database usage.

You could create a Model (e.g.) Document and easily use existing versioning systems, like [paper_trail](http://rubygems.org/gems/paper_trail). When using an indexed search, you can just have an has_many relation enabling you to realise the depencies between the models (destroy a model means to destroy the search index).

Comment: Just to be clear, wouldn't I be using the "rails way" if I were referencing these text entries?  For example, in a Rails photo app, the management is handled with references to the static image files (they're not stored as blobs in the database, right?).

Comment: Well using a Document-Modell to implement search, versioning and so on will be a must. Writing the photos to disc is usual, because they aren't often changed and have a big size, so it's the work to synchronise the database-system and the filesystem. In your case, there will be(imo) too many depencies on "one" document and the size is tiny compared to an image, so you don't have the need to take load off your databases...

Comment: sry for that typo:  Writing the photos to disc is usual, because they aren't often changed and have a big size, so it's **worth** the work to synchronise the database-system and the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a cut-off, you could look at what databases provide and ask yourself if those features would be useful. Take Isolation (the I in [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)): if you have any worries that multiple people could be trying to edit an entry at the same time, a database would handle that well while you'd have to handle the locks yourself working with files. Or Atomicity: you might want to update two things at once (e.g. an index page and an entry page) and know they will either both succeed or both fail.

Databases do a number of things beyond ACID, such as taking advantage of multiple datatypes, making querying easier, and allowing for scaling. It's a question worth asking since most databases end up having data stored in a bunch of files on disk. Would you end up writing a mini-database if you used files yourself?

Besides, if you're using rails you mind as well take advantage of its ActiveRecord functionality, and make it possible to use the many plugins that expect a database.

I'd use a database for even a small, single user rails app.